# JProfiller HeapWalker: This view is not available when retained size calculation has been disabled jprofiler

Tags: java, jprofiler, heap-dump, heap-profiling

I am a newbie to JProfiler. I am trying to figure out retained and deep size of an object in java. However, I'm getting **n/a** for all objects in Heap Walker. Also when I'm trying to check Biggest Object, following message has been shown.

"**This view is not available when retained size calculation has been disabled jprofiler**"

I checked profiling setting but couldn't find any option to enable/disable retained size calculation there.

Could someone please help me to fix this issue in Jprofiler?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Retained size calculation is enabled by default and can be disabled in 2 ways:

1. In the options dialog that is shown when you take the heap snapshot

[image]

2. In the progress dialog while the heap dump is being analyzed, by clicking on the "Skip" hyperlink during the retain size calculation phase.

[image]